# My btc to refill my cardrockcafe was never recieved

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app

I send  0.007 btc to the following address : 18pdflGW7Mz6KqXFTjX7bg7Ta3grhMCJYK. 
BUT THEY never received it.but my btc account is been deducted that amount.can u pls check into that and tell me what to do or what I did wrong.thanx

Comment: The address you're referring to is not valid. Please double check. Also, what wallet or service are you using?

Comment: What's the transaction ID of your payment?